# How to configure azurerm_site_recovery_replicated_vm on terraform with with AzureDiskEncryption

Tags: azure, terraform, disaster-recovery, azure-site-recovery

I 'd ask for some help to make works the failover vm from WE to NE , configured with terraform in azure.

This is the testing scenario:

```
I have 2 windows vm, created in the same way, with os disk encrypted with AzureDiskEncryption extension, with exactly the same parameters on both cases on WE region.KeyVaults are the same on both VM 's so the permissions are ok. Difference is that on the vm#1 the secret is not created by terraform (it'
```

s created automatically from Azure when DR is configured from portal) and in the vm #2 I had to create it (copy from the target) on the NE region because it's required for the configuration parameters on target_disk_encryption (param: secret_url).

vm 1 : I configured the disaster recovery manually from azure portal and failover test to NE region worked successfully.

vm 2 : I configured the disaster recovery through the azurerm_site_recovery_replicated_vm resource, I created through terraform a new secret on NE keyvault with the same name and value than in WE kv, because it's required by target_disk_encryption parameter, and when I test the failover to NE region I get the following error:

> Virtual machine 'vm-02' could not be created under resource group
> 'RG_DR' due to the following error: 'Unwrap of secret
> https://ne-kv-01.vault.azure.net/secrets/xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxx/xxxxxx
> value using key
> https://ne-kv-01.vault.azure.net/keys/we-enc-key-test-01/xxxxx
> failed.' Possible causes Unwrap operation on the secret for disk
> encryption key failed. Recommendation Ensure that you have the
> appropriate permission (Unwrap Key) to unwrap the secret.

This is the test code:

VM creation:

```
windows_virtual_machine_params = {
        win_vm_02 = {
            name = local.vm02
            resource_group_name = module.resource_group .0.resource_groups\["rg_01"\].name
            location = module.resource_group .0.resource_groups\["rg_01"\].location
            admin_username = "admin"
            admin_password = "${data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.sec-kv.value}"
            network_interface_ids = \ [module.network .0.network_interfaces\["ni02"\].id\]
            size = "Standard_D4ds_v5"
            tags = module.tagging.module_tags
            identity = [{
                type = "SystemAssigned"
                identity_ids = []
            }]

            os_disk = [{
                caching = "ReadWrite"
                storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
                diff_disk_settings = []
                disk_encryption_set_id = null
                disk_size_gb = null`your text`
                name = "test-`your text`osdisk-02"
                secure_vm_disk_encryption_set_id = null
                security_encryption_type = null
                write_accelerator_enabled = null
            }]

            source_image_reference = [{
                publisher = "MicrosoftWindowsServer"
                offer = "WindowsServer"
                sku = "2019-Datacenter"
                version = "latest"
            }]
        }

        winvm_ext02 = {
            name = "AzureDiskEncryption"
            virtual_machine_id = module.virtualmachinewindows .0.windows_virtual_machines\["win_vm_02"\].id
            publisher = "Microsoft.Azure.Security"
            type = "AzureDiskEncryption"
            type_handler_version = "2.2"
            auto_upgrade_minor_version = true
            automatic_upgrade_enabled = null
            settings = \ < \ < SETTINGS {
                "EncryptionOperation": "EnableEncryption",
                "KeyVaultURL": "${data.azurerm_key_vault.enc_kv.vault_uri}",
                "KeyVaultResourceId": "${data.azurerm_key_vault.enc_kv.id}",
                "KeyEncryptionKeyURL": "${data.azurerm_key_vault_key.enc_kv.id}",
                "KekVaultResourceId": "${data.azurerm_key_vault.enc_kv.id}",
                "KeyEncryptionAlgorithm": "RSA-OAEP",
                "VolumeType": "All"
            }
            SETTINGS

            protected_settings = null
            tags = module.tagging.module_tags
            depends_on = [
                module.virtualmachinewindows .0.windows_virtual_machines["win_vm_02"]
            ]
        }
```

Site Recovery Settings

```
site_recovery_replicated_vm_params = {
            srrvmp_01 = {
                name = local.vm02 - asr
                resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.asr.name
                recovery_vault_name = data.azurerm_recovery_services_vault.vault.name
                recovery_replication_policy_id = data.azurerm_site_recovery_replication_policy.policy.id
                source_recovery_fabric_name = data.azurerm_site_recovery_fabric.we.name
                source_vm_id = module.virtualmachinewindows .0.windows_virtual_machines\["win_vm_02"\].id
                source_recovery_protection_container_name = data.azurerm_site_recovery_protection_container.we.name

                target_resource_group_id = module.resource_group_dr .0.resource_groups["rg_dr_01"].id
                target_recovery_fabric_id = data.azurerm_site_recovery_fabric.ne.id
                target_recovery_protection_container_id = data.azurerm_site_recovery_protection_container.ne.id

                target_availability_set_id = null
                target_zone = null
                target_edge_zone = null
                target_proximity_placement_group_id = null
                target_boot_diagnostic_storage_account_id = null
                target_capacity_reservation_group_id = null
                target_virtual_machine_scale_set_id = null
                target_network_id = data.azurerm_virtual_network.ne.id
                test_network_id = data.azurerm_virtual_network.ne.id
                multi_vm_group_name = null
                managed_disk = [{
                    disk_id = data.azurerm_managed_disk.osdisk_02.id
                    staging_storage_account_id = data.azurerm_storage_account.rsv.id
                    target_resource_group_id = module.resource_group_dr .0.resource_groups["rg_dr_01"].id
                    target_disk_type = module.virtualmachinewindows .0.windows_virtual_machines["win_vm_02"].os_disk[0].storage_account_type
                    target_replica_disk_type = module.virtualmachinewindows .0.windows_virtual_machines["win_vm_02"].os_disk[0].storage_account_type

                    target_disk_encryption_set_id = null
                    target_disk_encryption = [{
                        disk_encryption_key = [{
                            secret_url = module.keyvault.secrets["disk_02_replica"].id
                            vault_id = "${data.azurerm_key_vault.asr_enc_kv.id}"
                        }]
                        key_encryption_key = [{
                            key_url = "${data.azurerm_key_vault_key.asr_enc_kv.id}"
                            vault_id = "${data.azurerm_key_vault.asr_enc_kv.id}"
                        }]
                    }]
                }]
                unmanaged_disk = []

                network_interface = [{
                    source_network_interface_id = module.network .0.network_interfaces["ni02"].id
                    target_static_ip = null
                    target_subnet_name = data.azurerm_subnet.subnet_ne.name
                    recovery_public_ip_address_id = null
                    failover_test_static_ip = null
                    failover_test_subnet_name = data.azurerm_subnet.subnet_ne.name
                    failover_test_public_ip_address_id = null
                }]
            }
        }
```

Data sources

```
    Key Vaults Definitions
        data "azurerm_key_vault"
        "enc_kv" {
            name = "we-kv-test-01"
            resource_group_name = "RG_TEST_01"
        }

        data "azurerm_key_vault"
        "asr_enc_kv" {
            name = "we-kv-test-01-asr"
            resource_group_name = "RG_TEST_01_asr"
        }

        data "azurerm_key_vault_key"
        "enc_kv" {
            name = "we-enc-key-test-01"
            key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.enc_kv.id
        }

        data "azurerm_key_vault_key"
        "asr_enc_kv" {
            name = "we-enc-key-test-01"
            key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.asr_enc_kv.id
        }

        data "azurerm_key_vault_secret"
        "enc_kv_02" {
            name = split("/", data.azurerm_managed_disk.osdisk_02.encryption_settings\[0\].disk_encryption_key\[0\].secret_url)\[4\]
            key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.enc_kv.id
            depends_on = \ [
                module.virtualmachinewindows\
            ]
        }
```

Also I created the secret from the failover vm copying the target secret into source region:

```
            disk_02_replica = {
                name = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.enc_kv_02.name
                key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.asr_enc_kv.id
                value = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.enc_kv_02.value
                content_type = "Wrapped BEK"
                not_before_date = null
                expiration_date = null
                tags = {
                    DiskEncryptionKeyFileName = "${data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.enc_kv_02.name}.BEK"
                    VolumeLetter = "C:\\"
                    VolumeLabel = "Windows"
                    MachineName = local.vm02
                    DiskEncryptionKeyEncryptionKeyURL = "${data.azurerm_key_vault.enc_kv.vault_uri}"
                    DiskEncryptionKeyEncryptionAlgorithm = "RSA-OAEP"
                }
```

Excuse meif is not very clear but I 'm not sure which other information I can provide for clarifications, but any suggestions are much appreciated.

in summary: Someone has used before the terraform resource site_recovery_replicated_vm and target_disk_encryption option with OS encrypted disks ? Please could provide me an example ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Virtual machine 'vm-02' could not be created under resource group 'RG_DR' due to the following error: 'Unwrap of secret https://ne-kv-01.vault.azure.net/secrets/xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxx/xxxxxx value using key https://ne-kv-01.vault.azure.net/keys/we-enc-key-test-01/xxxxx failed.' Possible causes Unwrap operation on the secret for disk encryption key failed. Recommendation Ensure that you have the appropriate permission (Unwrap Key) to unwrap the secret.

The reason for the above error is that you encountered `insufficient privileges` to decrypt the wrapped key from the `Key Vault`

This process ensures that only authorized entities with the necessary permissions can access and use the disk encryption key.

In order to resolve the issue, you should check and adjust the permissions associated with the identity or service attempting the **unwrap** operation in `Azure Key Vault`.

If you are using an access policy, make sure you have **Unwrap Key** selected for the wrapping operation. If you are using `Azure role-based access control`, you need the **Key Vault Crypto User** role. Follow the [Ms Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#key-vault-crypto-user) for more details.

[image]

**Terraform Code:**

```
resource "azurerm_windows_virtual_machine" "myvm" {
  name                = "venkat-vm"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  network_interface_ids = [azurerm_network_interface.samplenic.id]
  size                 = "Standard_B4ms"
  admin_username       = "Venkat"
  admin_password       = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.sec-kv.value

 identity{
      type = "SystemAssigned"
  }

  os_disk {
    name              = "VM-osdisk"
    caching           = "ReadWrite"
    storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
    disk_encryption_set_id = null
    secure_vm_disk_encryption_set_id = null
    security_encryption_type = null
    write_accelerator_enabled = null
  }
 
  source_image_reference {
    publisher = "MicrosoftWindowsServer"
    offer     = "WindowsServer"
    sku       = "2019-Datacenter"
    version   = "latest"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "disk-encryption" {
  name                 = "DiskEncryption"
  #location             = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  #resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_machine_id   = azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.myvm.id
  publisher            = "Microsoft.Azure.Security"
  type                 = "AzureDiskEncryption"
  type_handler_version = "2.2"

  settings = <<SETTINGS
{
       "EncryptionOperation": "EnableEncryption",
        "KeyVaultURL": "${data.azurerm_key_vault.enc_kv.vault_uri}",
        "KeyVaultResourceId": "${data.azurerm_key_vault.enc_kv.id}",
        "KeyEncryptionKeyURL": "${data.azurerm_key_vault_key.enc_kv.id}",
        "KekVaultResourceId": "${data.azurerm_key_vault.enc_kv.id}",
        "KeyEncryptionAlgorithm": "RSA-OAEP",
        "VolumeType": "All"
}
SETTINGS
}
```

**Terraform Apply:**

[image]