# Terraform: How to pass a list of managed_disk in RSV module

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-site-recovery

In Terraform how do I tell azurerm_site_recovery_replicated_vm that I have more than one disk to replicate?

For simplicity, I have a virtual machine with 3 disks (1 OS disk and 2 Data disks) on the west coast that I want to set up Azure Site Recovery (ASR) for replication to the east coast.

This is what I have so far.

The folder structure to contain the Terraform code.

```
Modules
  KeyVault
  PublicIP
  RecoverServiceVault
  BunchOfOtherAzureResources
Project01
Project02
Project03
Project0x
```

In **Project01**, In **main.tf**:

```
data "azurerm_managed_disk" "os_disk" {
  name                = local.osDiskName
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_virtual_machine.host.resource_group_name
}

module "AddRecoveryServiceVault" {
  source                       = "../modules/RecoveryServiceVault"
  rgDr                         = azurerm_resource_group.dr.name
  rgAsr                        = azurerm_resource_group.asr.name
  .  <bunch of other parameters passed to the module>
  .  <bunch of other parameters passed to the module>
  
  sourceDiskId                 = data.azurerm_managed_disk.os_disk.id

  .  <bunch of other parameters passed to the module>
  .  <bunch of other parameters passed to the module>
  tags                         = local.tags
}
```

Currently, **the module** ‘RecoveryServiceVault’ takes one disk.
In **variables.tf**:

```
variable "sourceDiskId" {
  type = string
  description = "the disk Id of the virtual machine being protected in Source (Primary)"
}
```

In **main.tf**:

```
resource "azurerm_site_recovery_replicated_vm" "vm-replication" {
  name                                      = var.sourceHostName
  resource_group_name                       = var.rgDr
  recovery_vault_name                       = azurerm_recovery_services_vault.vault.name
  source_recovery_fabric_name               = azurerm_site_recovery_fabric.primary.name
  source_vm_id                              = var.sourceHostId
  recovery_replication_policy_id            = azurerm_site_recovery_replication_policy.policy.id
  source_recovery_protection_container_name = azurerm_site_recovery_protection_container.primary.name

  target_resource_group_id                = var.rgAsrId
  target_recovery_fabric_id               = azurerm_site_recovery_fabric.secondary.id
  target_recovery_protection_container_id = azurerm_site_recovery_protection_container.secondary.id

  managed_disk {
    disk_id                    = var.sourceDiskId
    staging_storage_account_id = var.storageAccountId
    target_resource_group_id   = var.rgAsrId
    target_disk_type           = "Premium_LRS"
    target_replica_disk_type   = "Premium_LRS"
  }

  network_interface {
    source_network_interface_id   = var.sourceNicId
    target_subnet_name            = azurerm_subnet.secondary.name
    recovery_public_ip_address_id = azurerm_public_ip.secondary.id
  }

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_site_recovery_protection_container_mapping.container-mapping,
    azurerm_site_recovery_network_mapping.network-mapping,
  ]
}
```

My guess is that you’ll need to do this.
Create a list of Object of (managed_disk) in **Project01 main.tf**

```
module "AddRecoveryServiceVault" {
  source = "../modules/RecoveryServiceVault"
  rgDr   = azurerm_resource_group.dr.name
  rgAsr  = azurerm_resource_group.asr.name
  .  <bunch of other parameters passed to the module>
  .  <bunch of other parameters passed to the module>

  managed_disk = [{
    disk_id                    = "osDisk01Id"
    staging_storage_account_id = "stId"
    target_resource_group_id   = "rgId"
    target_disk_type           = "Premium_LRS"
    target_replica_disk_type   = "Premium_LRS"
    },
    {
      disk_id                    = "dataDisk01Id"
      staging_storage_account_id = "stId"
      target_resource_group_id   = "rgId"
      target_disk_type           = "Premium_LRS"
      target_replica_disk_type   = "Premium_LRS"
    },
    {
      disk_id                    = "dataDisk02Id"
      staging_storage_account_id = "stId"
      target_resource_group_id   = "rgId"
      target_disk_type           = "Premium_LRS"
      target_replica_disk_type   = "Premium_LRS"
  }]
  .  <bunch of other parameters passed to the module>
  .  <bunch of other parameters passed to the module>

  tags = local.tags
}
```

Passed the list of objects (managed_disk) to **the module** ‘RecoveryServiceVault’ of azurerm_site_recovery_replicated_vm

In **variables.tf** of the RecoverServiceVault module

```
variable "managed_disk" {
  type =  list(object({
    disk_id                    = string
    staging_storage_account_id = string
    target_resource_group_id   = string
    target_disk_type           = string
    target_replica_disk_type   = string
  }))
}
```

In the **main.tf** of the **RecoverServiceVault** module, I am unable to pass the list of objects to managed_disk

[image: UnableToPassListOfManaged_Disks]

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Where exactly is that error showing up? When calling the module or inside of the module code? Based on that, you need to define a variable called `managed_disk`.

Comment: Hi @scv, Check this [Stack Overflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77955394/azure-vm-data-disk-replication-is-failing-using-terraform/78028487#78028487) for replicating one or more disks to a Recovery Service Vault using Terraform, answered by me

Comment: @MarkoE, it can be confusing to follow the code when you're not behind VS Code. The error happens "In variables.tf of the RecoverServiceVault module". There is a variable defined as "managed_disk" as a list of objects, but when it is being assigned to managed_disk of azurerm_site_recovery_replicated_vm, it does not recognize "var.managed_disk".

Comment: @VenkatV, are you saying that 'managed_disk' cannot accept an array of objects, but you can have multiple instances of 'managed_disk'. So, for Project01, I will need another module that handles 3 disks? For vm with 2 disks, I would need another module for 2 disks? Thanks!

Comment: @VenkatV, I saw an example here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77495209/how-to-configure-azurerm-site-recovery-replicated-vm-on-terraform-with-with-azur where managed_disk is assigned an array. Maybe that wouldn't work.

Comment: In your case, You can add one managed disk for the operating system and another one for data storage in site recovery replicated block modile , Inside the second managed disk, you can use for each to add multiple data disks.